# Can I recreate a temp table after dropping it?

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedures, temp-tables

**Given:**

code inside a stored proc:

```
select bleh
  into #tblTemp
  from FunctionThatReturnsTable('some','params')

-- do some stuff

drop table #tblTemp

-- Error on this command:
-- 'There is already an object named '#tblTemp' in the database.'
select bleh
  into #tblTemp
  from FunctionThatReturnsTable('some','other params')
```

**Problem:**

I can't recreate this temp table. My work around is to use #tmpTable1, #tmpTable2, #tempTable3 etc. Is there a way I can get around this? It would be nice just use one temp table each time.

If not, what is the reason for this?

Comment: Why do you need to keep re-using the same #temp table name? I'd suggest that you would get better schema behavior in tempdb if you don't drop the #temp table and use a different name for each specific purpose. This may or may not be true in your case but I don't see the benefit of re-using the same name over and over again.

Comment: @AaronBertrand I agree that reusing variables isn't the best but I'm pulling the same columns from the same function every time. With out going into too much detail, it just made sense to keep the same variable name.

Can you tell me why this isn't possible in an answer? If so, I'll upvote and mark as an answer.

Comment: If you are using the same temporary table with the same columns each time, just use `delete` or `truncate` to clear the table and change your subsequent `select into` statements to `insert` into the existing table.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

As my comment reflected, I'm going to suggest that the answer is that you use a different #temp table name for each object that you create. It's kind of like saying to the doctor, "it hurts when I do this." His likely response is going to be, "stop doing that!"

The reason this is a problem is that SQL Server's parser attempts to parse the entire batch in one shot. It can clearly see that you are trying to create the same #temp table multiple times, but ignores the `DROP` command in between (I can't tell you exactly why that is, as I don't have access to the source code). This is the same reason you can't do this:

```
IF (1=1)
  CREATE TABLE #foo(i INT);
ELSE
  CREATE TABLE #foo(i VARCHAR(32));
```

The parser sees the two identical names, but can't really follow the `IF/ELSE` logic.

In addition to avoiding the problems multiple identically-named #temp tables causes the parser, another benefit to using unique names is that they *can* be re-used if you don't explicitly drop them. This will lighten the load on tempdb in terms of metadata / locking.

Comment: Thanks Aaron, I appreciate the answer to this.

Answer (score 1):

This is a feature by design and is clarified by Microsoft against Microsoft Connect Bug ID 666430

Please see a case study on the same at
[temporary-table-could-not-be-re-created](http://www.tectalks.com/493/temporary-table-could-not-be-re-created/)

Comment: Your link "temporary-table-could-not-be-re-created" is broken. Do you know whether that information is still available somewhere?

Answer (score 0):

I ran into this problem with deleting+inserting column. The problem is probably with the parser, that it 'recognizes' the table on first create, and cannot see it was deleted.

I'd suggest using `exec sp_executesql 'create table'`

Comment: This actually means that the OP will have to do all of the work with the #temp table inside of dynamic SQL, since beyond the exec that table you created in dynamic SQL no longer exists. I don't think this is an elegant solution at all.

Comment: It should work with a global temp table though.