# Unable to create temp table with same name but in different condition

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2012, temp-tables

if cnt=1 then I want to create a temp table with 2 columns when cnt = 2 then I want a temp table with 3 columns but with the same name as below.

```
Declare @cnt int
Set @cnt = 2

IF @cnt = 1
Begin
if OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#temptest') is not null drop table #temptest;
create table #temptest
(   ID int,
    M1 char(2)
);
end


IF @cnt = 2
begin

if OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#temptest') is not null drop table #temptest;
create table #temptest
(   ID int,
    M1 char(2),
    M2 char(2)
);
end
```

am getting an error

> 'There is already an object named '#temptest' in the database.

How to do this.. please help?

Comment: The parser will stop you from doing that before your logic is ever examined (see [this question for some background](https://stackoverflow.com/q/9812302/61305)). And even if you do this (dynamically generate the create table for example), you still won't be able to _reference_ `M2` in later portions of the code unless all of that code _also_ uses dynamic SQL. Why don't you just create all three columns and ignore the 3rd column when `@cnt = 2`?

Comment: @shivkumar . . . Create the temporary table with two columns and add an extra column using `alter table` if necessary.

Comment: @Gordon But if you have later code that references `M2`, it will fail when `@cnt = 1`. In which case, if you have to surround every later statement with the same `IF` logic, may as well just create two different tables.

Comment: @shivkumar you can also find more details [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18776603/cannot-create-the-same-temp-table-twice-in-the-same-batch)

Comment: @AaronBertrand/Gordon linoff Thank you for your comments. yes am using alter table to add extra columns based on IF condition and it's working. Also am using these tables in dynamic sql to execute.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The easiest solution would be to create the temp table with the minimum columns needed, then add columns as necessary based on the value for @cnt. Try this:

```
DECLARE @cnt int
SET @cnt = 2

IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#temptest') is not null DROP TABLE #temptest;
CREATE TABLE #temptest
(   ID int,
    M1 char(2)
);

IF @cnt = 2
BEGIN

ALTER TABLE #temptest
ADD M2 char(2)

END
```